# What difference between NEventStore and EventStoreDB

Tags: cqrs, neventstore, ncqrs, eventstoredb

Recently I'm learning CQRS and want to change my system to use event-sourcing patterns.

But I found that on .Net platform, there is two Event Store implementations.

0. [NEventStore(formerly JOliver EventStore)](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore)
1. [EventStoreDB(from EventStore.com)](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore)

The two implementations confuse me - can someone please explain the key differences between them.

Comment: They are completely different products. They are alike in the sense that they both implement *Event Sourcing*, but they are very different. It's like comparing Sql Server with mysql.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg Thanks for your commenting, in my concept, there is no many different between SqlServer and MySQL.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg Perhaps more like comparing SQLite to RavenDB ? (as in one can be embedded into your app regardless of what sort of deployment arrangement you have and deliberately doesn't try to cover everything end to end whereas GetEventStore is a much bigger and powerful thing but also necessarily more complex and less adaptable [from a deployment perspective]). Anyone have a better contrasting set of examples - happy to delete this one when it's been bettered!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

NEventStore is a persistence agnostic event sourcing library for .NET with multiple storage options such as relational and document databases.

EventStoreDB is a newer and high performing event sourcing solution with its own persistence engine and API's for multiple protocols and languages. It has open source and commercial options.

As far as I know you can use EventStoreDB as a persistence engine for NEventStore in a future version of NEventStore as well.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to mentioned EventStoreDB and NEventStore there is relatively new [SQLStreamStore library](https://github.com/SQLStreamStore/SQLStreamStore), that conceptually similar to NEventStore.

They have a few essential differences, but historically SQLStreamStore can be consider as a successor of NEventStore. The author of the SQLStreamStore [damianh](https://github.com/damianh) previously was  a maintainer of NEventStore. The latest release of NEventStore was 15 Mar 2014, SQLStreamStore is actively developing.

For more details why SqlStreamStore was created see the answer [SQLStreamStore vs NEventStore vs EventStore #108](https://github.com/SQLStreamStore/SQLStreamStore/issues/108#issuecomment-348154346)